# Can I use multiple instances of Play Server that log to same file on disk?

Tags: java, logging, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am using play file logger in multiple applications like below:

```
Class1.java
private static ALogger logger = Logger.of("myAppLogger");
public void someMethodOfClass1() {
logger.info("This is Class1");
}

Class2.java
private static ALogger logger = Logger.of("myAppLogger");
public void someMethodOfClass2() {
logger.info("This is Class2");
}

Class3.java
Class4.java
```

and so on

Now, If I run multiple instances of play server (or one instance of server and one instance with `new play.api.Application` to run batch script) on same machine, is it valid and recommended to use multiple server instances with one file logger ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play framework uses the Logback logging framework.

I suggest you should take a look at the documentation of Logback's [File Appender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#FileAppender). According to the documentation, `FileAppender` supports a prudent mode that is by default set to false.

> In prudent mode, FileAppender will safely write to the specified file,
>   even in the presence of other FileAppender instances running in
>   different JVMs, potentially running on different hosts. The default
>   value for prudent mode is false.

But the same page warns:

> Prudent mode relies on exclusive file locks. Experiments show that
>   file locks approximately triple (x3) the cost of writing a logging
>   event. On an "average" PC writing to a file located on a local hard
>   disk, when prudent mode is off, it takes about 10 microseconds to
>   write a single logging event. When prudent mode is on, it takes
>   approximately 30 microseconds to output a single logging event. This
>   translates to logging throughput of 100'000 events per second when
>   prudent mode is off and approximately 33'000 events per second in
>   prudent mode.

It is not clear from the documentation what would happen if you try to log from several jvm's while the prudent mode is off.

Answer (score 1):

It calls slf4j LoggerFactory.getLogger(name) for each Logger.of() call so it should be safe to do it like that.